# Bind a value to CSS via angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-directive

I hope this is a simple enough problem:

I have a directive which needs to add a left and right margin to the element its added to (a class directive) based on the value of a variable I pass in via isolate scope.

The problem I'm having is now to bind it. If I were directly writing it directly, it'd be something like:

```
<div ng-style="{'left-margin': myVar}">asdf</div>
```

But I have no idea how I can get that added via a directive. Or if I can at all. I'm tempted to create a watch and set it via jQuery, but I know that's the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Are those margins supposed to be updated if the value passed via isolate scope changes?

Comment: what about setting myVar in the controller? if its a constant $scope.myVar = 20px; if it is dynamic and needs a function $scope.myVar = function() { }

Comment: They only need to be set once, but they're determined by another directive. I'm currently doing it via jQuery, but since that's linear, it doesn't have that problem. In this case, I have an ng-if showing content, which then triggers one directive to determine the margin widths, which this then needs to use. Once set, it won't be changing.

Comment: The problem, user2707389, is I don't know how to bind myVar in a class directive to the element the class is on. The variable already exists; I need to bind it to the actual element.

Comment: This is a lot trickier because of the class directive limitation. Is this for super old browsers? Or can we solve this using attribute directive?

Comment: I can switch to attribute directives, its fine. Class directive is definitely more convenient, but is not a necessity. If I can figure out how to do this binding, I can always use the directive to add the necessary class to the element.